# Way to iterate over only part of a data-frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame (`df`) indexed by date that the head looks like:

```
            dept            ratio
      date  
01/01/1979     B      0.522576565
01/01/1979     A      0.940614079
01/01/1979     C      0.873957946
01/01/1979     B      0.087828824
01/01/1979     A      0.397543450
01/01/1979     A      0.475491609
01/01/1979     B      0.140605283
01/01/1979     A      0.071007362
01/01/1979     B      0.480720923
01/01/1979     A      0.673142643
01/01/1979     C      0.735542710
```

I also have a `threshold` variable that is static and set to `2.0`

I'm trying to create a column called `higher` that compares the ratio for a Dept against all other ratios that are in the same Dept (but not against itself). Creating a count where the value calculated is greater than the threshold value.

For example for the first row I would compare the ratio value `0.241223` against all other `Depts` that have a value `B`:

```
0.522576565/0.087828824 > 2.0 = True
0.522576565/0.140605283 > 2.0 = True
0.522576565/0.480720923 > 2.0 = False
```

So the first value in the `higher` column would be 2 (2 caparisons are higher than the threshold).  So my desired output would look like:

```
         dept            ratio  higher
      date     
01/01/1979    B    0.522576565       2
01/01/1979    A    0.940614079       2
01/01/1979    C    0.873957946       0
01/01/1979    B    0.087828824       0
01/01/1979    A    0.397543450       1
01/01/1979    A    0.475491609       1
01/01/1979    B    0.140605283       0
01/01/1979    A    0.071007362       0
01/01/1979    B    0.480720923       2
01/01/1979    A    0.673142643       1
01/01/1979    C    0.735542710       0
```

I have created some code but it's very slow. Please see below:

```
threshold = 2
for idxDay, row in df.iterrows():
                Id = idxDay
                ratio = row["ratio"]
                dept = row["dept"]
                DeptCount=0
                MyCount=0
                MyLong=0
                for idxRange, row1 in df.iterrows():
                    rangeId = idxRange
                    rangeRatio = row1["ratio"]
                    rangeDept = row1["dept"]

                    if dept== rangeDept and Id != rangeId:
                        DeptCount = DeptCount + 1

                        if (ratio/rangeRatio) > threshold :
                            MyCount = MyCount + 1

                df.loc[idxDay, "higher"]=MyCount
```

Is there a quicker way to do this?

Comment: Unless there is a good reason not to do so, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `broadcasting` to compare the values within each group:

```
def compare(x):
    return (x[:,None] > 2*x).sum(-1)

df['higher'] = df.groupby('dept')['ratio'].transform(lambda x: compare(x.values))
```

Output:

```
           dept     ratio  higher
date                             
01/01/1979    B  0.522577     2.0
01/01/1979    A  0.940614     2.0
01/01/1979    C  0.873958     0.0
01/01/1979    B  0.087829     0.0
01/01/1979    A  0.397543     1.0
01/01/1979    A  0.475492     1.0
01/01/1979    B  0.140605     0.0
01/01/1979    A  0.071007     0.0
01/01/1979    B  0.480721     2.0
01/01/1979    A  0.673143     1.0
01/01/1979    C  0.735543     0.0
```